# Composer throws PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found when deploying

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, monolog, vendor

So here's my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/support": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1.9",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.4.2",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.11.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1.8",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^3.3.4",
    "sentry/sentry": "^1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "0.7.0 as 0.6.2",
    "phenx/php-font-lib": "0.4 as 0.2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

I have a local version that works perfectly fine, but when I try to deploy to our server I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 28 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

I've looked everywhere and the only fixes I've found were to manually download and add ResettableInterface.php and place it in the monolog vendor directory but I can't do that as it's installed then tested automatically by the deployer script and if it fails it won't deploy so I don't get a chance to do this. What do I do?

Comment: Are you running `composer install` or `composer update`?

Comment: composer install --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

Comment: It pulls a fresh site install from git and then runs installation for the dependencies

Comment: In that case, it's possible your existing composer lock file has some mismatched dependencies. You could try running `composer update` again, committing the new lock file, and then redeploying to see if that resolves the missing class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing or renaming the vendor folder and Composer.lock file. Now run composer install . This will create the vendor folder with all its new dependencies.